# Why does this Eloquent relationship return null in a foreach loop?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a relationship that's acting weird. If I get the results and `dd()`, it has the correct data. However, if I run the collection through a `foreach` loop it's like the relationship disappears.

The `users` table has a field called `referred_by`, which stores the user ID of the person who referred the user. In my instance I'm looking for all the new users who were referred by the user with the ID of `3`.

Here's the relationship in `User.php`

```
public function referrer()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'referred_by');
}
```

Here's the code which is returning funky results

```
$users = User::where('referred_by', 3)
    ->with('referrer')
    ->get();

// doing dd() here returns a collection with full referrer relationship;
// the returned data is as expected

dd($users);

foreach($users as $user)
{
    // dd($user) here returns the relationship, as it should

    // dd($user->referrer) here returns null, like the relationship doesn't exist
}
```

Comment: please post the output of `dd($users);`, and in the for loop `dd($user);` and `dd($user->referrer);`

Comment: That is quite weird. I wasn't able to reproduce this with your exact code. See [this](https://implode.io/mrbTm9)

Comment: @Mozammil Yes, it was a stupid mistake on my part; see my answer. Thanks for your assistance. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
foreach($users as $user)
{
    // dd($user) here returns the relationship, as it should

    dd($user['referrer'])
}
```

Rather then

```
 // dd($user->referrer)
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had a database column on the `users` table named `referrer` that was causing an issue. I changed the relationship's method name from `referrer()` to `referredBy()` and it worked. *eyeroll*